# Thread.sleep called in loop - what is the proper way to use the delay while repainting the component?

Tags: java, swing

I have created the loop, which periodically repaints component:

```
public class A extends Thread {

  private Component component;
  private float scaleFactors[];
  private RescaleOp op;

  public A (Component component){
  this.component = component;
  }

  public void run(){

    float i = 0.05f;
    while (true) {

        scaleFactors = new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, i};
        op = new RescaleOp(scaleFactors, offsets, null);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(...)
        }
        component.repaint();
        i += step;
      }

    }

}
```

But in this case I get the message (NetBeans 7.3.1):

> Thread.sleep called in loop

Maybe there is better solution in this situation?

Comment: component.repaint(timeout)

Comment: But if I remove `Thread.sleep(timeout)` and do for example `component.repaint(1000)` - the loop finishes instantly, without any delays..

Comment: i see, i was a little to fast :p, see Timer as mentioned below

Comment: Minor point: In general, when you sleep in the body of a loop, the try/catch(InterruptedException) should be *outside* the loop, since an interrupt literally represents a request from another thread to stop what you are doing and exit (as gracefully as possible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swing is single threaded. Calling `Thread.sleep` in the `EDT`prevents UI updates.

I suggest using a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead. It was designed to interact with Swing components.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(timeout, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        component.repaint();
    }
});
timer.start();
```

*Edit:*

Stopping a timer from within its own `ActionListener` is typically done using

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Timer timer = (Timer) e.getSource();
    timer.stop();
}
```

Comment: In this case I have to set `timer.setRepeats(true);` - but how then I stop it from inside the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method?